# modify oppacity in iBox javascript file

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I wish to use the [iBox](http://www.ibegin.com/labs/ibox/) plugin but I don't know how to:
1) disable image resize.
2) modify the opacity of the background.

I was trying to modify the ibox.js file and I think that opacity starts from line 330.
many thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) disable image resize.

I didn't test it, but try to add can_resize:false option into line 755 of ibox.js

_pub.html(img, {width: this.width, height: this.height, constrain: true, **can_resize: false**})

> 2) modify the opacity of the background.

do you mean the black overlay? IMO, you have to modify the bg.png file (see images folder)